# Extract elements of a specific tag using beautiful-soup

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract elements from a specific tag. For example - there are four in a site. And each tag has other siblings tags like p,h3,h4,ul and so on. I want to see h2[1] elements, h2[2] elements separately.

This is what I have done so far. I know for loop doesn't make any sense. I also tried to append text but couldn't make it successful. Then I tried searching by a specific string, but it gives the only tag of that specific string, not all other elements

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = "https://www.us-cert.gov/ics/advisories/icsma-20-079-01"
resp = requests.get(page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, "html5lib")
content_div=soup.find('div', {"class": "content"})
all_p= content_div.find_all('p')
all_h2=content_div.find_all('h2')
i=0
for h2 in all_h2:
  print(all_h2[i],'\n\n')
  print(all_p[i],'\n')
  i=i+1
```

Also tried using append

```
 tags = soup.find_all('div', {"class": "content"})
 container = []
 for tag in tags:
  try:
    container.append(tag.text)
    print(tag.text)
  except:
    print(tag)
```

I am a total newbie in programming. Please pardon my poor coding skills. All I want is to see everything under "mitigation" together. So that if I want to store it in DB it will parse everything related to mitigation on one column.

Comment: do you want to extract the raw test of each h2 body or extract all the template (title + text of each header body and subheader body such as h3 / h4) ?

Comment: I am looking to extract all the template under h2[0],h2[1],h2[3] and so on. Now I can extract the whole report or I can extract a specific tag. But I can't separate h2[0] from h2[1]....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look for a static list of tags `["p","ul","h2","div"]` using `findNext` with `recursive=False` to stay on the top level :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

resp = requests.get("https://www.us-cert.gov/ics/advisories/icsma-20-079-01")
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, "html.parser")

content_div = soup.find('div', {"class": "content"})

h2_list = [ i for i in content_div.find_all("h2")]
result = []
search_tags = ["p","ul","h2","div"]

def getChildren(tag): 
    text = []
    while (tag):
        tag = tag.findNext(search_tags, recursive=False)
        if (tag is None):
            break
        elif (tag.name == "div") or (tag.name == "h2"):
            break
        else:
            text.append(tag.text.strip())
    return "".join(text)

for i in h2_list:
    result.append({
        "name": i.text.strip(),
        "children": getChildren(i)
    })

print(json.dumps(result, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```